The dimension of $k$ over $k$
Let $(R, \mathfrak{m}, k)$ be a local ring, and suppose we have a ring map $\varphi: k\to R$ so $R$ is a $k$-algebra via $\varphi$. Then $R/\mathfrak{m}\simeq k$ (as $R$-module) has a natural structure of $k$-vector space via $\varphi$. Then how can I show this has a dimension one?
Background:  I tried to check two definitions of intersection multiplicity of curves are equal, namely $\dim_k \mathcal{O}_x/(f,g)=\text{length}_{\mathcal{O}_x}\mathcal{O}_x/(f,g)$. If $k$ is algebraically closed, then it is easy to reduce to that question, but I have stuck on a weird problem. Now I'm wondering if we have to assume some kind of compatibility condition, for example $\varphi$ is a splitting map of $0\to \mathfrak{m}\to R\to k\to 0$.

In general, the residue field of $R$ is not the same as the base field. Is that an additional assumption you are making?

Yes I'm trying to solving the latter problem when $k$ is algebraically closed. So in the first question, I forced the base field to be the residue field $k$ by $\varphi$ (although I guess my problem is checking such $k$ is indeed a "base" field in some sense).

Even for $k$ algebraically closed the two fields will not be the same in general. Consider the case where $R$ is a transcendental field extension.

I'm not sure what do you mean by two fields. There is only one field $k$ in first paragraph, and for the second paragraph I'm simply considering intersection on regular surface.

Let $\pi: R \to R/m = k$ be the projection. Then define $\Phi:= \pi \circ \varphi$. The $k$-vector space structure on $k$ via $\varphi$ is then given by $\lambda\cdot v = \Phi(\lambda)v$ for $\lambda,v \in k$.
It is $\dim_k k = 1$ if and only if $\{1\}$ is a $k$-basis of $k$ (since $1\neq 0$). Further, $\{1\}$ is a $k$-basis of $k$ if and only if for every $v \in k$ there is some $\lambda \in k$ with $v = \lambda\cdot 1 = \Phi(\lambda)1 = \Phi(\lambda)$, i.e. $\Phi$ is surjective ($\iff \Phi$ is an automorphism of $k$).
An example where $\Phi$ is not surjective would be $R=k=K(X_0,X_1,X_2,\dots)$ (i.e. $\pi = \text{id}_k $) and $\varphi = \Phi: K(X_0,X_1,X_2,\dots) \to K(X_0,X_1,X_2,\dots), X_i \mapsto X_{i+1}$. Then $X_0 \notin \text{Im}(\Phi)$. Therefore $\dim_k k > 1$.

If $k$ is algebraically closed and $\varphi \colon k \to R$ is essentially of finite type (meaning it is the localization of a finite type $k$-algebra), you can argue as follows:
The map $k \overset{\varphi}{\to} R \twoheadrightarrow R/\mathfrak{m}$ is of finite type, hence by the weak Nullstellensatz $k \hookrightarrow R/\mathfrak{m}$ is a finite field extension. Since $k$ is algebraically closed, this is a trivial extension, so $\dim_k R/\mathfrak{m} = 1$.
The argument works slightly more generally as long as $k$ has no proper finite extension (abstractly) isomorphic to itself.
This is for example the case if $k$ is algebraic over its prime field $\mathbb{F}$ (either $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{F}_p$): If $k \subsetneq \ell$ is a proper finite extension and $\alpha \in \ell \setminus k$, then $\operatorname{minpol}_{\alpha/\mathbb{F}}(t) \in \mathbb{F}[t]$ has a root in $\ell$ but not in $k$, so these fields are not abstractly isomorphic.
If these assumptions are not satisfied, then the residue field can indeed be a proper extension of $k$.

Let $R = \mathbb{Q}(t) = k$, $n\geq 2$ and $\varphi \colon k \to k$ the embedding $\varphi(x) = x^n$, then $k \hookrightarrow k$ has degree $n$.
If $R$ is not essentially of finite type over $k$ then this can fail even if $k$ is algebraically closed: Let $k = \overline{\mathbb{Q}(x_1,x_2,\dots)}$ be an algebraic closure of the function field in infinitely many variables, then there exist non-surjective field homomorphisms $k \to k$, for example the one induced by $x_i \mapsto x_{i+1}$. This is essentially the same example psl2Z gave while I typed this up.


Thank you. I see that the Nullstellensatz works nicely for the finite type case, which is what I need. Still, it seems I should accept psl2Z's answer, as he posted it earlier with a valid counterexample while I was thinking in terms of arbitrary local rings. I'll upvote instead :)
